# Show / Hide paragraph with angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to show a message after an action being executed on angular. So I have:

```
<p class="notice">{{model.notice}}</p>
```

And on my controller I have:

```
$scope.model = {
  notice: ''
};
```

Later on I change the notice value and the message is shown.

The problem is the P Html tag is always visible ...

I would like to hide it when notice has nothing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<p class="notice" ng-hide="model.notice == ''">{{model.notice}}</p>
```

also, `ng-hide` can test the truthiness of a variable, you could also do:

```
<p class="notice" ng-hide="model.notice">{{model.notice}}</p>
```

but be careful of variables with a `0` (falsy) value.

Comment: I would also recommend this, but try using `ng-if` for situations like messaging as it will not be added to the DOM. `ng-hide` is using `display: none!important` where `ng-if` simply doesn't add it as HTML unless truthy.